# Mocking a struct field's methods

Tags: go, mocking

I'm working on a simple golang server app that does OAuth authentication. The server code is straight forward. For unit tests, I need to avoid making external HTTP requests to the actual OAuth provider.

So during normal Server operation, I would like to use the real calls, and when running `go test`, use a Mock method to prevent external HTTP requests.

I've created mocks of the OAuth methods, but I don't understand the mechanics of how to integrate them into the code. Looking through mock examples, I'm still confused about how a mock interface is used.

Here's the original code:

```
type Server struct {
    //This is the actual golang.org/x/oauth2 Config struct
    oauth2Config  *oauth2.Config
}


func (s *Server) handleCallback() http.HandlerFunc {
    // This is the method that makes external call. I want to mock it
    oauth2Token, err := s.oauth2Config.Exchange(s.context, r.URL.Query().Get("code"))
}
```

I define an interface, and the mock function

```
type Oauth2ConfigInterface interface {
    Exchange(ctx context.Context, code string, opts ...oauth2.AuthCodeOption) (*oauth2.Token, error)
}

type MockOauth2Config struct {
}

func (o *MockOauth2Config) Exchange(ctx context.Context, code string, opts ...oauth2.AuthCodeOption) (*oauth2.Token, error) {
    return &oauth2.Token{}, nil
}
```

I would have thought I should change the original Server struct to use the new interface:

- On normal Server operation, oauth2Config field is assigned with &oath2.Config{}
- On tests, oauth2Config field is assigned with &MockOauth2Config{}

```
type Server struct {
    //Changed to interface
    oauth2Config  Oauth2ConfigInterface
}

...

        oauth2Config: &oauth2.Config{
            ClientID:     "",
            ClientSecret: "",
            RedirectURL:  "",
            Scopes:       []string{oidc.ScopeOpenID},
        },
```

But when I try to access the fields of oauth2Config, it gives me compile errors.

```
// compile error here
s.verifier = s.provider.Verifier(&oidc.Config{ClientID: s.oauth2Config.ClientID})
```

Once oauth2Config has been declared an interface, how can I access the fields?

Or am I doing this whole mock wrong?

Comment: *"when I try to populate oauth2Config struct with values"* -- Once you change the `oauth2Config` field to `Oauth2ConfigInterface` it is no longer a struct, it is an interface. You can always initialize the config *before* assigning it to the `oauth2Config` field, or even after as long as you retain the pointer to it, but I assume you already know that, can you perhaps explain what stops you from doing that?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/vektra/mockery to generate Mocks for testing

Comment: @mkopriva Yes I can initialize the config before assigning to `oauth2Config` field, but when I try to access the fields (e.g. s.oauth2Config.ClientID) I get compile error. How do you retain the pointer to it? I know I'm asking a stupid question, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: I edited the bottom part of original question to better explain my issue. Thanks.

Comment: @IssMeftah Thanks but before using any mock generator/framework, I would like to do it myself to understand the mechanics of it.

Comment: The **static** type of `oauth2Config` is `Oauth2ConfigInterface`, which is an interface type. Interface types do NOT have fields. Interface types are sets of zero or more methods. Nothing else. That is why: "but when I try to access the fields (e.g. s.oauth2Config.ClientID) I get compile error".

Comment: Hmm ok, is there a way to switch oauth2Config between the actual oauth.Config and my MockConfig?

Comment: I think maybe I went down the wrong path and asked the wrong question here. My real question is really, if I have to store a field that's a struct, and it has methods on it. How can I create a mock for those methods?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/TpFQF4MwVSI

Comment: You can't mock methods of concrete types. You can only mock interface methods (and function values). So, if you want to mock `oauth2.Config` methods, then your original approach of creating an interface and using that instead of the concrete type is valid.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I understand now.

Comment: The simplest way to mock out struct methods is to inject a function rather than invoking the method directly; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68940230/how-to-mock-net-interface/68941591#68941591

Comment: @bcmills Wow, that's very elegant. I'll integrate that into my code and answer my own question if successful. Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock net.Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68940230/how-to-mock-net-interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question...

I may have phrased my question badly but I do think people in the future will run into the same question.

@bcmills gave the best solution:
[How to mock net.Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68940230/how-to-mock-net-interface/68941591#68941591)

It is far more elegant than mocking using interface. Especially for a case like this where third-party func/methods are involved.